# How to rename files and subdirectories in bash command line?

Tags: bash, mv, recursion

In Rails sometimes I need to rename several directories and files, e.g.:

```
app/models/person.rb
app/views/persons/_person.haml
app/controllers/persons_controller.rb
----
app/models/user.rb
app/views/users/_user.haml
app/controllers/users_controller.rb
```

I've exhausted looking up solutions. Does anyone know of a simple command line tool that I can install? E.g. `mvall . person user`.

Comment: Look at the Related questions on the right column. There are lot of answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but here's my implementation.

```
$ old=person; new=user; for i in $(find ./ -name "*$old*"); do mv $i $(echo $i | sed 's/'$old'/'$new'/g'); done
```

All the tools are in bash, so nothing needs to be installed.

Comment: You could also use `find` to execute your changes (rather than just locate the targets), It probably depends on whether you're more comfortable with `find` or `bash`.

Comment: @Rusty: `for i in $(find . …)` will fail if there are filenames that contain spaces.  And you don’t need to say “`./`”.

Comment: @Dominic: Is `find` guaranteed to behave sanely if you rename directories while it is traversing the directory tree?

Comment: @Scott - good question. Don't know the answer